# Gogot Engine error issue: "body set shape disabled" and "body set shape as one-way collision"

Tags: runtime-error, godot, gdscript

I have a problem with the engine Godot, with the errors "body set shape disabled" and "body set shape as one-way collision".

In my project I have built four scenes:

- The `platform` scene formed by (`StaticBody2D` which has as child objects(`CollisionShape2D`, `Sprite`, `Position2D`, `Area2D` which in turn has a child object(`Collisionshape2D`))
- The `missile` scene formed by (`RigidBody2D` which has as child objects(`CollisionShape2D` and `Sprite`));
- The `spaceship` scene formed by (`Kinematicbody2D` which has as child objects(`Sprite` and `CollisionShape2D`));
- The `main` scene which has as root node `Node` and as child objects: (platform and spaceship).

Moreover I have two scripts: one in the `spaceship` scene, on the `Kinematicbody2D` node; and then in the `platform` scene on the `StaticBody2D` node.

Basically when I start the game there is the `platform` at the top center and then there is the `Area2D` (with the `CollisionShape2D` to detect when a body enters the area and then there is also the `Position2D` that I set for a position where it should instantiate the missile at runtime).

When a body enters the `Area2D` the `platform` should instantiate a `missile` (which does nothing for the moment).

The problem arises when I direct the `spaceship` in the `Area2D` and the `platform` instantiates many times (more than 200-300 times per second) the missile and this is the moment when the game crashes. I get the errors that I wrote above and then I have to close it.

**Spaceship Code:**

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var target
var click
var dir
var collision
var speed = 200

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        target = get_global_mouse_position()
        click = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    if click:
        dir = position.direction_to(target)
        collision = move_and_collide(dir * speed * delta)
        if collision:
            pass
```

**Platform Code:**

```
extends StaticBody2D

var trigger
var missileScene = preload("res://scenes/Missile.tscn")
var missile

func _on_DangerArea_body_entered(body):
    if body is KinematicBody2D:
        trigger = true
    while(trigger):
        missile = missileScene.instance()
        $SpawnPosition.add_child(missile)
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(3),"timeout")

func _on_DangerArea_body_exited(body):
    if body is KinematicBody2D:
        trigger = false
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 3.2.1. Can't change this state while flushing queries. Use call\_deferred() or set\_deferred() to change monitoring state instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206231/godot-3-2-1-cant-change-this-state-while-flushing-queries-use-call-deferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal `body_entered` will happen for each `PhysicsBody2D` (`KinematicBody2D`, `RigidBody2D`, `StaticBody2D`) that enters the `Area2D`. And that includes the missiles.

Yes, you are checking if the body is a `KinematicBody2D`. But when a `KinematicBody2D` enters, it sets `trigger` to true, allowing all bodies to enter the loop.

First of all, I suggest to reject bodies by returning:

```
func _on_DangerArea_body_entered(body):
    if not body is KinematicBody2D:
        return

    # ...
```

And second, you can use a regular timer to spawn missiles (and that way, you also know that there is at most one timer running):

```
extends StaticBody2D

var timer:Timer
var missileScene:PackedScene = preload("res://scenes/Missile.tscn")

func _ready():
    timer = Timer.new()
    add_child(timer)
    timer.set_wait_time(3)
    timer.connect("timeout", self, "instance_missile")

func _on_DangerArea_body_entered(body):
    if not body is KinematicBody2D:
        return

    timer.start()

func _on_DangerArea_body_exited(body):
    if not body is KinematicBody2D:
        return

    timer.stop()

func instance_missile():
    var missile := missileScene.instance()
    $SpawnPosition.add_child(missile)
```

*The following might or might not be useful in your game: You can use [node groups](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#groups), or [register classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#register-scripts-as-classes) so you can be more specific than `is KinematicBody2D`. Another thing you can do is add the bodies you care about to an `Array` when they enter, and remove them when they exit, so you know when they all exited.*

---

By the way, the first thing I noticed while transcribing the code: You never set `click` to false (or something other than true).

It appears you want to handle click for one physics frame. For that you don't need `_input`. Use [`Input.is_action_just_pressed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-is-action-just-pressed) in `_physics_process` instead. *In fact, I would encourage to begin that way, and only move to `_input` if you need to. And a lot of times you don't.*

Comment: Thank you but I would like to ask you exactly where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Gius My understanding of what happens is the following: The `KinematicBody2D` enters the `Area2D`, then the code sets `trigger` to true, spawns a missile, and yields on a timer. Now the recently spawned missile entered the `Area2D`, `trigger` is already true, so it spawns a missile, and yields on a timer. Now the recently spawned missile entered the `Area2D`, `trigger` is already true, so it spawns a missile, and yields on a timer. Now the recently spawned missile entered the `Area2D`, `trigger` is already true, so it spawns a missile, and so on. *I hope that makes sense.*

Comment: No I mean what I did wrong in the code, that is, what mistake I made in the code I wrote at the beginning.  More precisely, I mean the mistake I made that caused me to generate the two errors in the question I asked..

Comment: @Gius The errors, for what I understand the errors are from the functions [`body_set_shape_disabled`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2dserver.html#class-physics2dserver-method-body-set-shape-disabled) and [`body_set_shape_as_one_way_collision`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2dserver.html#class-physics2dserver-method-body-set-shape-as-one-way-collision). I don't know what exactly the errors were.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same error today , this is my guess.

You can't directly add a rigid body (my case) while on a physics frame (like on area enter).

The `add_child` process may trigger some engine code stuff and they're not allowed to process on the physics frame.

So ,the workaround is: just try replace `$SpawnPosition.add_child(missile)` with `$SpawnPosition.call_defered("add_child",missile)` and it'll work.